# FFmpeg Images to Video and Streaming

Tags: image, streaming, ffmpeg, vlc, transcoding

I've a C# program generating JPEG images in realtime, i need to (continuously) generate a video from the images and stream it (also in realtime).

I've used ffmpeg to transcode an input video source and stream it, doesn't ffmpeg have an option to get the input as a set of images(always being generated) and make the video out of it ?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I used VLC for the streaming....

Actually I just found at that I could:
ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%d.jpg /tmp/a.mpg

But i need to tell ffmpeg to keep doing it, I mean, if it doesn't find another image ffmpeg should wait for another one to be generated... is this possible ?

Comment: Did you manage to make ffmpeg wait? I need something similar.